# Randomly Distribute percentages to each words

Tags: java, random

```
Percentage:70 - CommandA  Data:Previous/New(80/20)    User:true/false(50/50)
Percentage:30 - CommandB  Data:Previous/New(50/50)    User:true/false(30/70)
```

Above is my Text File in which I am printing CommandA 70% of the time and CommandB 30% of the time from the logic **that I wrote below by getting advice here from StackOverflow**. Now what I want is that if CommandA is being printed 70% of the time, then 80% of the 70$ of time, it should also prints Previous and 20% of the 70% of time it should print New. Similarly it should print 50% of the 70% of time true and 50% of the time false.
So Basically problem is like this- Problem Statement

---

> Print "CommandA" 70% of the time, and out of those 70% print 80%
>   "Previous" and print 20% "New". And out of those 70% print 50% "true"
>   and print 50% "false" Likewise, for CommandB print "CommandB" 30% of the
>   time, and out of those 30% print 50% "Previous" and print 50% "New".
>   And out of those 30% print 30% "true" and print 70% "false"

---

So currently in my below code I am printing 70% of CommandA and 30% of CommandB. I am not sure how should I add the code for above requirements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        commands = new LinkedList<Command>();
        values = new ArrayList<String>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("S:\\Testing\\Test2.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            percentage = sCurrentLine.split("-")[0].split(":")[1].trim();
            values = Arrays.asList(sCurrentLine.split("-")[1].trim().split("\\s+"));
            for(String s : values) {
                if(s.contains("Data:")) {
                // Here data contains **Previous/New(80/20)**
                    data = s.split(":")[1];
                } else if(s.contains("User:")) {
                // Here userLogged contains **true/false(50/50)**
                    userLogged = s.split(":")[1];
                } else {
                    cmdName = s;
                }
            }

            Command command = new Command();
            command.setName(cmdName);
            command.setExecutionPercentage(Double.parseDouble(percentage));
            command.setDataCriteria(data);
            command.setUserLogging(userLogged);
            commands.add(command);
        }

        executedFrequency = new Long[commands.size()];

        for (int i=0; i < commands.size(); i++) {
            executedFrequency[i] = 0L;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
            Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
    // So by my logic each command is being printed specified number of percentage times                    
    System.out.println(nextCommand.getName()); 


/*
 * What I want is that if Command A is executed 70% of time, then according 
 * to properties  file 80% times of 70% of CommandA it should print Previous 
 * and 20% times of 70% of CommandA it should print New Likewise same thing 
 * for User. It should print 50% times of 70% of CommandA true and 50% to false.
 * 
 */

        }
    } 

}

// Get the next command to execute based on percentages
private static Command getNextCommandToExecute() {
    int commandWithMaxNegativeOffset = 0; // To initiate, assume the first one has the max negative offset
    if (totalExecuted != 0) {
        // Manipulate that who has max negative offset from its desired execution
        double executedPercentage = ((double)executedFrequency[commandWithMaxNegativeOffset] / (double)totalExecuted) * 100;
        double offsetOfCommandWithMaxNegative = executedPercentage - commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).getExecutionPercentage();

        for (int j=1; j < commands.size(); j++) {
            double executedPercentageOfCurrentCommand = ((double)executedFrequency[j] / (double)totalExecuted) * 100;
            double offsetOfCurrentCommand = executedPercentageOfCurrentCommand - commands.get(j).getExecutionPercentage();

            if (offsetOfCurrentCommand < offsetOfCommandWithMaxNegative) {
                offsetOfCommandWithMaxNegative = offsetOfCurrentCommand;
                commandWithMaxNegativeOffset = j;
            }
        }
    }

    // Next command to execute is the one with max negative offset
    executedFrequency[commandWithMaxNegativeOffset] ++;
    totalExecuted ++;

    return commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset);
}
```

P.S. The logic that I wrote for percentage execution is from the posting that I did on the stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't see any randomness in the listed code

Comment: Randomness is there in the sense which command is being picked basis on the weight. Or what can be the best way to do this problem from the scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `java.util.Random` class to generate random numbers.  The `Random.nextDouble()` method returns a value between 0 and 1, so if you multiply that with 100 you get a percentage.  Then compare the number against the desired percentage for the command (e.g. 70 for `CommandA`)

Since you know the desired percentages for the commands, you can either generate another random number or use the one just generated for the selection of the command.

1. *generate a new number*: (see above for the generation), then you can compare the percentage against the desired second level distribution (e.g. 80 for `Previous`)
2. *reuse the same number*: calculate the appropriate part of the command selection treshold and compare the number against that.  E.g. for `CommandA` the treshold is 70.  Let's say you generated 69 (which is less than 70, thus `CommandA` was chosen).  So you calculate 70*80%=56.  69 is greater than that, so you select `New` (instead of `Previous`)

*Note*: you could do approach 1) even if you kept your current logic of selecting the command

Update: code example:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
double percent = rnd.getNextDouble()*100;
for (Command c : commands) {
  if (percent < c.getExecutionPercentage()) {
    // we select the current command
    percent = rnd.getNextDouble()*100;
    if (percent < command.getDataCriteria().getPreviousPercentage()) {
      // we select Previous
    } else {
      // we select New
    }
    break;
  } else {
    percent -= c.getExecutionPercentage();
  }
}
```

*Note*: the above code assumes that the sum of all `Command`s `getExecutionPercentage()` is (at least) 100

Update: made a `Random` object as the methods are not static

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you give me one example that fulfills my above requirement as by that way I can understand more and make the changes required.

Comment: Are you sure by this way it will be executed the required number of percenatges time? I am still unsure.

Comment: Because the way you are calculating the percentage, it is possible that few things will not be executed the required percentage time?

Comment: Example: execution percentages: 10(A), 15(B), 30(C), 40(D), 5(E), random number generated: 66, expected selection: D; Execution: `percent=66`, _A_: `66<10` - false -> `percent=56`, _B_: `56<15` - false -> `percent=41`, _C_: `41<30` - false -> `percent=11`, _D_: `11<40` - true -> _D_ selected.  If you are still unsure, write a small test program with the suggested logic and run it 100 (or even 10000) times and see whether the percentages work out